# C# Min Max Connect R game Grid Filling issue

Tags: c#, arrays, minimax

I'm having an issue with my Connect R program. I can have it play playervsplayer just fine but, there is something wrong wit my MinMax that I don't understand. I pass in my 2D array into the algorithm in order to traverse it and have the PlaceT algorithm in my MinMax to add into a temporary 2D array for when I recursively call the MinMax. For some reason it actually adds it to my main 2Darray so by the time the function ends its filled up when I only wanted one item to be added. I included both the PlaceT function as well as the MinMax. I also did include a picture for reference

The idea is to traverse through the 2D array from the bottom and if there is a blank space than add to a temp 2D array than recall the Max recursively, and it does this till the traversal ends. then it takes all the added moves and sees which one has the most score than returns that to the main MinMax which is supposed to be used to place the tile where its supposed to go. Let me know if you want to see any of the other code outside of those algorithms.

```
        static void PlaceT(int ogC, int ogR, int c, int r, string[,] board, string id)
    {
            if (id == "R")
            {
                if(r - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    if (board[r - 1, c] == "R" || board[r - 1, c] == "B")
                    {
                        PlaceT(ogC, ogR, c, r - 1, board, id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        board[r - 1, c] = "R";
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (id == "B")
            {
                if(r - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    if (board[r - 1, c] == "B" || board[r - 1, c] == "R")
                    {
                        PlaceT(ogC, ogR, c, r - 1, board, id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        board[r - 1, c] = "B";
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    static void MinMax(string [,] board, int row, int col, string ID, int count, string otherID, bool isComp)
    {
        string[,] tempB = board;
        AIMove bestmove = new AIMove();
        bestmove.x = MaxMove(tempB, row, col, ID, count, otherID, isComp).x;
        PlaceT(col, row, bestmove.x, row, board, ID);
        return;
    }

    static AIMove MaxMove(string[,] board, int row, int col, string ID, int count, string otherID, bool isComp)
    {
        AIMove move = new AIMove();
        string[,] grid =  new string[row,col]; 
        grid = board;
        if (isFull(grid))
        {
            move.score = 0;
            return move;
        }
        else if(rInRow(grid, count, row, col, ID) == 10)
           {
               move.score = 10;
               return move;
           }
       else if(rInRow(grid, count, row, col, otherID) == 10)
           {
               move.score = -10;
               return move;
           }
           List<AIMove> moves = new List<AIMove>();
            for (int y = row - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                for (int x = col - 1; x >= 0; x--)
                {
                    if (grid[y, x] != "R" && grid[y, x] != "B")
                    {
                        move.x = x;
                        move.y = y;
                        if(isComp)
                        {
                            PlaceT(col, row, move.x, row, grid, ID);
                            isComp = !isComp;
                            move.score = MaxMove(grid, row, col, ID, count, otherID, isComp).score;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PlaceT(col, row, move.x, row, grid, otherID);
                            isComp = !isComp;
                            move.score = MaxMove(grid, row, col, ID, count, otherID, isComp).score;
                        }
                        moves.Add(move);
                    }
                }

            }
            grid = board;
            int _best = 0;
            if(isComp)
            {
                int _bestScore = -100;
                for (int i = 0; i < moves.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (moves[i].score > _best)
                    {
                        _best = i;
                        _bestScore = moves[i].score;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int _bestScore = 100;
                for (int i = 0; i < moves.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (moves[i].score < _best)
                    {
                        _best = i;
                        _bestScore = moves[i].score;
                    }
                }
            }
            return moves[_best];
    }
```

[Image of Program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UyBJ.png)

Comment: You say you want "the PlaceT algorithm in my MinMax to add into a temporary 2D array for when I recursively call the MinMax"? So why can't you just make a copy of the array (board I think?) and pass that PlaceT if you don't want it to actually affect the real board state?

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing with                                                  string[,] grid =  new string[row,col]; 
grid = board;

Comment: That's just two assignments, first assigns a new array to the variable grid, second assigns board to grid, causing board and grid to both have the same assignment and that array that you just constructed gets thrown away. If you want to copy it, you'll need to copy every element into the new array.